# Why am I losing my SwiftUI View when switching screens

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an SwiftUI based native WatchOS app.  I have 4 views that the user can swipe left and right to get to.  This feature is not directly a SwiftUI feature so I am using WKInterfaceController.reloadRootConrollers(withNamesandContext:) However the screen sometimes just loads a blank screen when swiping.  I don't see anything wrong in this code...

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class HostingController : WKHostingController<MeetingView> {
    override init(){
        super.init()

        displayViews()
    }

    func displayViews() {
        WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNamesAndContexts: [
            (name: "OneViewController", context: [:] as AnyObject),
            (name: "TwoViewController", context: [:] as AnyObject),
            (name: "ThreeViewController", context: [:] as AnyObject),
            (name: "FourViewController", context: [:] as AnyObject),
        ])
    }

    override var body: MainView {
        return MainView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. Happens also while using storyboard.

Comment: Wonder if it is a just a bug in WAtchOS6?

Comment: Trying to figure out what to say in a bug report to apple.

Comment: Possibly. I managed to reproduce this issue in other apps as well. For example Strava - Swipe fast back and forth couple of times and view will eventually disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to have been a WatchOS bug... it is no longer a problem.